# Failed to select option by post data in jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup

HTML is like:

```
<form method="post" action="stepB1.asp" name="form1" id="Form1" onsubmit="return CheckData();">
<select name="syear" class="inputbox" id="Select1">
    <option value="104">104</option>
    <option value="105">105</option>
</select> YEAR
<select name="smonth" class="inputbox" id="Select2">
    <option value="01"> 1</option>
    <option value="02"> 2</option>
    <option value="03"> 3</option>
    <option value="04"> 4</option>
    <option value="05"> 5</option>
    <option value="06"> 6</option>
    <option value="07"> 7</option>
    <option value="08"> 8</option>
    <option value="09"> 9</option>
    <option value="10"> 10</option>
    <option value="11"> 11</option>
    <option value="12"> 12</option>
</select>
```

I use jsoup to parse the html as follows

```
Document docs = Jsoup.connect(param).timeout(3000).data("syear", "104").data("smonth", "07").post();
System.out.println(docs.toString());
```

then the result:

```
<form method="post" action="step.asp" name="form1" id="Form1" onsubmit="return CheckData();">
<select name="syear" class="inputbox" id="Select1">
   <option value="104">104</option>
   <option value="105">105</option>
</select> 
YEAR <select name="smonth" class="inputbox" id="Select2"> 
   <option value="01"> 1</option> 
   <option value="02"> 2</option> 
   <option value="03"> 3</option> 
   <option value="04"> 4</option> 
   <option value="05"> 5</option> 
   <option value="06"> 6</option> 
   <option value="07" selected> 7</option> 
   <option value="08"> 8</option> 
   <option value="09"> 9</option> 
   <option value="10"> 10</option> 
   <option value="11"> 11</option> 
   <option value="12"> 12</option> 
</select>
```

07 selected but `syear` no selected.
Any suggestion?

i expect the result:

```
    <select name="syear" class="inputbox" id="Select1">
     <option value="104" selected> 104</option>
     <option value="105">105</option>
    </select> 
     YEAR <select name="smonth" class="inputbox" id="Select2"> 
     <option value="01"> 1</option> 
     <option value="02"> 2</option> 
     <option value="03"> 3</option> 
     <option value="04"> 4</option> 
     <option value="05"> 5</option> 
     <option value="06"> 6</option> 
     <option value="07" selected> 7</option> 
     <option value="08"> 8</option> 
     <option value="09"> 9</option> 
     <option value="10"> 10</option> 
     <option value="11"> 11</option> 
     <option value="12"> 12</option> 
    </select>
```

Comment: Anyway what results ware you expecting and why?

Comment: Also your form tag seems to be closed right after you opened it. This doesn't seem right.

Comment: the tag </form>  is edited at wrong way. thanks!

Comment: i expect the result is like: <select name="syear" class="inputbox" id="Select1">
   <option value="104" selected>104</option>
   <option value="105">105</option>
</select>

Comment: Don't add important informations like expected results (and why it is expected) only in comment since not everyone is going to read comments which means you are limiting your chance of getting answer. Other problem is that comments don't provide proper code formatting. Instead [edit] your question and place these informations there.

Comment: What does `CheckData()` method in `onsubmit="return CheckData();"` do? Are you sure it doesn't change your sent values into something else (some format which server expects)?